# amsmaths alignat ignores first command in first line of equations

Tags: amsmath, alignat

I'm trying to use a `\nu` with a `\tilde` on top as the first symbol in the first line of a set of aligned equations using the `alignat` package.

minimal non-working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}
\tilde{\nu}
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

If I now added `\hphantom{}` in front of the `\tilde`. It works as intended. What I cannot wrap my head around though, is that not all commands get ignored. For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}
\Delta\tilde{\nu}
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

This also gives the proper Delta and nu with tilde on top. I got it working now, as using the `\hphantom{}` command gives me what I want, but this can not be the proper way, can it?

Comment: `\begin{alignat}{<number>}`

Comment: @egreg this indeed solves it, thank you.

Comment: Never ignore error messages, the result from your test file is `! Missing number, treated as zero.` after _any_ error the PDF is not intended to be usable, it may possibly be useful for debugging. If asking questions about an error condition it is better to quote the error message than to describe the output.

Answer (score 1):

As @egreg pointed out, if alignat is given the proper argument, which is the maximum number of & symbols in any one line +1 divided by two, as in \begin{alignat}{} (as seen here as well: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics)

thanks!